# Angular js apply color picker value

Tags: angularjs, colors, angularjs-ng-change

I want to apply the color picker runtime value as a background color of span text. How can I use model as a color value?

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="">
   <input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
   <input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
   <input type="text" name="abc" class="color" ng-model="abc" ng-change="myStyle={color:'green'}">
   <br/>
   <span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
   <pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
</body>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/APrl9Y98Em0d6rxuzRDE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the ng-model of your input.

```
<input type="text" name="abc" class="color" ng-model="color" ng-change="myStyle={'background-color':'#'+color}">
```

[your plunker with the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/yftGwoQxMvuQp2f7VeXD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I not really good understood what you want to do, but i think something like this:
when you choose some value in the color picker - your `span` backround color is set to that value. You can see this plunk:

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2QWZy5zwdmpND7vyEF03?p=preview

I added module and controller.